# xml в postgresql

Tags: база-данных, xml, postgresql, индексация, индексы

Есть документ в формате doc или docx.

Есть шаблон этого документа.

Он преобразуется в формат xml.

Необходимо положить этот xml файл в бд.
Чтобы потом было возможно наладить поиск по каким-то ключевым словам, индексам например и тд.

Интересуют статьи, примеры, гайды именно такой бд.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть в PgSQL [тип данных xml](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/datatype-xml.html), но если вам нужно искать потом по этому полю - он не подойдет (тип xml не участвует в выражениях условий выбора).

Гораздо интереснее дело обстоит с [данными JSON](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/datatype-json.html) - потом можно много чиво полезного делать з данными, запросы хитрые строить и пр. - в доке подробные примеры приведены. Поэтому рассмотрите вариант конвертации XML в JSON перед сохранением.

Если JSON по каким-то соображениям не подходит (например, XML не всегда можно в JSON сконвертировать без потерь) - тогда просто сохраните в поле text, создайте индекс типа GIN или GIST, и можно строить условия аля-полнотекстового поиска (в том числе комбинируя с обычными условиями и join-ами). Всё это также [подробнейшим образом описано в документации](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/textsearch.html). Если возникнут вопросы после чтения документации, что-то не смогли понять и пр. - тогда *конкретно те* вопросы и формулируйте.